# Docker is not running my php project via docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have my php project. In this project, is a public folder which contains the index.php as a starting point.

The docker-compose.yml file is in the root directory.

So

```
[Project root directory]

----docker-compose.yml
----public
----------index.php
----other project files and folders
```

Now I have my docker-compose.yml file, which contains a mysql, phpmyadmin, apache image and a link to the project itself.

It was working before, some weeks ago. I don't remember that I have changed something up, but it does not work anymore.

here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  php:
    image: docker.team23.de/docker/php:7.2
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
  web:
    image: docker.team23.de/docker/apache:2.4-php
    environment:
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /app/public
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "3039:80"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project_name
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

volumes:
  db:
```

docker-compose up -d -V

[docker-compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhcAK.png)

docker ps

[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftd2H.png)

the phpmyadmin works fine. I can login to mysql, so this is working too.

But if I open localhost:3039, which should run my project, I get :

The website is unavailable localhost has refused the connection.

logs of web image

```
Attaching to xxxx_web_1
web_1         | [Sun Jul 21 10:10:57.740369 2019] [so:warn] [pid 1:tid 140066424941416] AH01574: module setenvif_module is already loaded, skipping
web_1         | [Sun Jul 21 10:10:57.740410 2019] [so:warn] [pid 1:tid 140066424941416] AH01574: module headers_module is already loaded, skipping
web_1         | [Sun Jul 21 10:10:57.740417 2019] [so:warn] [pid 1:tid 140066424941416] AH01574: module alias_module is already loaded, skipping
web_1         | AH00526: Syntax error on line 14 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd-extra-basics.conf:
web_1         | DocumentRoot '/app/public' is not a directory, or is not readable
```

Comment: What does ```docker-compose logs web``` say?

Comment: I will edit my question. It seems like my public dic is not there or not readable

Comment: Mhh.. As we now, the public folder is there. So it is not readable?

Comment: If I do winpty docker-compose exec web bash, I get : ERROR: No container found for web_1

Comment: Use ```docker ps -a``` to make sure the container is running. If it's not, then you'll have to intercept the startup with something like: ```command: ['tail', '-f', '/dev/null']``` in order to exec bash inside.

Comment: if I do docker ps -a the apache image is running but with no port. The port column for this apache row is empty. I think this will be the problem

Comment: But I don't really understand what you mean with : command: ['tail', '-f', '/dev/null']

Comment: That is a line in the compose yaml file under the web service. It is a way to start the container and force it to run a program that won't end in the background, so that the container doesn't just instantly stop, and you can get inside it to see what's going on. It also prevents the "normal" startup script from running in almost all "official" docker images. It is equivalent to the ```COMMAND``` instruction in a dockerfile.

Comment: I found something like ENTRYPOINT: ['tail', '-f', '/dev/null'] - and I should put this at the end of my docker-compose.yml ? or still in the web section?

Comment: It has to be in the web service b/c it only applies to the web service.

Comment: okay, docker is executing my yml file with the entrypoint tail -f /dev/null but it still does not work

Comment: logs are also empty

Comment: Nothing will work until you fix it. The entrypoint was just to keep the container up long enough for you to exec into it.